# Easiest way to map objects attributes into Java Maps

Tags: java, dictionary

There are easy to use tool to serialize java class into JSON strings ([gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)), does any mainstream library, or java language feature, provide a similar functionality to map objects into java Maps?

The natural way to do that for class C1:

```
class C1
{
  private int x;
  private int y;

  public int getX() { return x; }
  public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }

  public int getY() { return y; }
  public void setY(int y) { this.y = y; }
}
```

And object o1:

```
C1 o1 = ...
```

... could be:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
result.put("x",o1.getX());
result.put("y",o1.getY());
```

The way gson works is quite straightforward (from gson website):

```
BagOfPrimitives obj = new BagOfPrimitives();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
```

I understand I can develop that tool by myself using something like:

```
Class.getDeclaredFields()
```

but I wonder if this functionality has already been included in any mainstream library.

Comment: http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/serialization/

Comment: `json4j` is used in Apache Wink. I used it and is ok.

Comment: @MacConan I don't want to serialize my object in a string or a file. I just need to generate a map where each entry key is an attribute name of the object and contains the object value for this attribute.

Comment: @Areo I don't need a tool to work with json, I just used gson as an example of the kind of interface that the tool I am looking for should have.

Comment: Ok. Iunderstand: Check this: <http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I decided to implement my own mapper:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Serializer {
    static public Map<String, Object> object2Map(Object o)
    {
        Class co = o.getClass();
        Field [] cfields = co.getDeclaredFields();
        Map<String, Object> ret = new HashMap<>();
        for(Field f: cfields)
        {
            String attributeName = f.getName();
            String getterMethodName = "get"
                               + attributeName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                               + attributeName.substring(1, attributeName.length());
            Method m = null;
            try {
                m = co.getMethod(getterMethodName);
                Object valObject = m.invoke(o);
                ret.put(attributeName, valObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                continue; 
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

A silly use example:

```
public class JavaUtilsTests {

    static public class C1
    {

        public C1(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }       

        public int getX() { return x; }
        public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }

        public int getY() { return y; }
        public void setY(int y) { this.y = y; }

        private int x;
        private int y;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C1 o1 = new C1(1,2);
        Map<String, Object> attributesMap = Serializer.object2Map(o1);
        System.out.printf("x=%s\ty=%s\n", attributesMap.get("x"), attributesMap.get("y"));
    }
}
```

My "mapper" method requires input objects to present getters and setters named by the following pattern:

(get|set)attributeTitledName

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with Jackson. Jackson is mainly used to convert objects to/from json.

### Maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

### Java Example

```
class C1 {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public int getX() { return x; }
    public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }

    public int getY() { return y; }
    public void setY(int y) { this.y = y; }

    public void main(String[] args) {
            C1 obj = new C1();
            obj.setX(10);
            obj.setY(20);

            Map<String, Object> map = new ObjectMapper().convertValue(obj, Map.class);
            System.out.println(map); 
    }

}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this some more. This is a great solution! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> Use this:commons-beanutils

```
File  file = new File();
PropertyDescriptor[] fileObjectDescriptors = 
                         PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(file);
List<PropertyDescriptor> filePropertyList = 
                      Arrays.asList(fileObjectDescriptors);
for(PropertyDescriptor fileProperty:filePropertyList){
    attribute = fileProperty.getName()
    value = PropertyUtils.getProperty(file, fileProperty.getName());
 }
```